# a fast way to join NLA strips?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

In the NLA editor, splitting strips is just a matter of one key press.
I did not find a similarly easy way to join them again (except ctrl-z :D)

So far, what I usually did, was:

- copy the last strip for reference
- delete all but the first strip
- adapt the length of the strip

If the strips belonged to two actions, it would even involve joining the actions by copy-paste and careful "trimming" of each action before.

Obviously, this cannot be the way how it's meant to be done :)

So my question is: How to do it correctly / efficiently and beginner-friendly?

(apologies if there is an answer to this question here. I searched the web for hours yesterday, but didn't find any)

Comment: You can use Bake Actions, while soloing the strips you want to join on their own track, to create a new action strip that combines the keyframes from both. Note that this will sample keyframes at regular intervals, instead of at their original positions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a menu option and keystroke <kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd> to create a Meta strip that groups multiple strips.

It sounds like you want to undo the splitting of a strip, but that same operation also has to have a defined behavior if the two strips selected were not originally split from the same source.

The logic to detect that two strips were originally split from the same source would be non-trivial and have a fairly long set of test cases for a QA team to perform.

Comment: The background was that I unintentionally split up multiple strips because I forgot to deselect the non-active one. I noticed when it was almost too late, and spent quite some time fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the NLA Tracks with the same word.
And they work as one.